# Atlas cluster - mongoimport "Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers"

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, mongodb-atlas, mongoimport

I'm learning MongoDB as of now, and I'm a relative newbie. I have a Mongo DB Atlas cluster on GCP. I am using Windows 10, and my PATH variable is set to the `bin` folder of the MongoDB server on my C Drive. 
I'm trying to import a json file (which has json array of documents) to my cluster using the following command -

```
mongoimport --host FOO_HOST-shard-00-00-pmipm.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 --db FOO_DB --collection FOO_info --file E:/FOO.json --username FOO_user --password FOOFOO --jsonArray
```

The error looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JanC7.png)

```
2019-11-23T14:22:12.683-0600    [........................] FOO_DB.FOO_info     0B/229B (0.0%)
2019-11-23T14:22:14.753-0600    [........................] FOO_DB.FOO_info     0B/229B (0.0%)
2019-11-23T14:22:14.753-0600    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2019-11-23T14:22:14.758-0600    imported 0 documents
```

I saw a bunch of related stackoverflow posts, but all of them have been resolved using simply localhost in place of the hostname in monogimport command, which I can't use. Can someone please help me understand if I'm missing something very obvious here?